# Switching javascript widget themes using document.write() method

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm trying switch the twitter javascript widgets out depending on the time. So in the day, the twitter widget will be colored differently than at night.

I used the code that twitter gave me and came up with this code. But I get a syntax error in DW on the "document.write" lines.

Here is the code that twitter gave me...

```
<script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<script>
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'search',
  search: '@BigNotch',
  interval: 6000,
  title: 'Follow Me On Twitter',
  subject: 'BigNotch',
  width: 180,
  height: 300,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#17d1ff',
      color: '#ff8fda'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#ededed',
      color: '#383838',
      links: '#ff8aed'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: true,
    live: true,
    hashtags: true,
    timestamp: true,
    avatars: true,
    toptweets: true,
    behavior: 'default'
  }
}).render().start();
</script>
```

Here is the complete code that I put together. I get an error on line 88. The document.write line.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function changTwitter() {
var currentTime = new Date().getHours();    

 if (7 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 17) {

       document.write('<' + 'script>
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'search',
  search: '@BigNotch',
  interval: 6000,
  title: 'Follow Me On Twitter',
  subject: 'BigNotch',
  width: 180,
  height: 300,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#242124',
      color: '#f0af4d'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#333333',
      color: '#c2c2c2',
      links: '#f7bc63'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: true,
    live: true,
    hashtags: true,
    timestamp: true,
    avatars: true,
    toptweets: true,
    behavior: 'default'
  }
}).render().start();
</' + 'script> ');   
 }

 else {
      document.write('<' + 'script>
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'search',
  search: '@BigNotch',
  interval: 6000,
  title: 'Follow Me On Twitter',
  subject: 'BigNotch',
  width: 180,
  height: 300,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#17d1ff',
      color: '#ff8fda'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#ededed',
      color: '#383838',
      links: '#ff8aed'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: true,
    live: true,
    hashtags: true,
    timestamp: true,
    avatars: true,
    toptweets: true,
    behavior: 'default'
  }
}).render().start();
</' + 'script> ');

  }

      }


changeTwitter();
-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use document.write to add inline JavaScript code. It will not run the code. There is also no reason to use document.write there.

Just call the methods.